Is it possible to use Particle Marginal Metropolis Hastings to estimate the transition matrix and input?
A state space model is defined as:
$$x_{t+1} = A_tx_t + B_tu_t$$
$$y_{t+1} = H_tx_{t+1}$$
So my question is: is it possible to use Particle Marginal Metropolis Hastings to estimate the transition matrix $$A_t$$ and the input $$u_t$$ given the observations, matrix H and B?
